# Error when running python script

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am running the below python script.

```
Price = []
Item = input("Enter the price of each item and seperate each price by line. Enter the blank line once you entered all prices. ")
while Item != "":
    Item = input("")
    Price.append(Item)
print(Price)
```

And I am getting the below error. Please help.

```
/Users/piyush/PycharmProjects/Test1/venv/bin/python /Users/piyush/Desktop/LearningProgramming/Python/Exercises/Exercise3/3.64.py
Enter the price of each item and seperate each price by line. Enter the blank line once you entered all prices. 12
23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/piyush/Desktop/LearningProgramming/Python/Exercises/Exercise3/3.64.py", line 11, in <module>
    Item=input("")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Upgrade to python 3 or use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: I have checked and raw_input function is working. Can I ask you one question? Why input function is not working in this scenario in python 2.7?

Comment: @Piyush `input()` tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression, it's like `eval(raw_input())`

Comment: @Piyush Which is explained at the duplicate question, did you bother to read it?

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I like that duplicate better.

Comment: @Barmar, I have gone through the duplicate question and now it is clear to me. Thanks a lot for helping me.